# Sample page layout spoils in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, bootstrap-4

I just made a sample facebook signup page using html5, css3 and bootstrap 4 only (using rows and columns). I'll be grateful, if someone takes a look at it and advises me. also the layout gets spoiled in chrome while works fine in firefox. I'm using wamp and accessing the page via localhost!

Any help is appreciated.

This is the view from:

[Chrome:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KRe8.jpg)

Here is the view from [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHgVF.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

    <head>

        <!-- Charset -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <!-- Responsive -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0 shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- styelsheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/custom-styles.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/101f6b4938.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <!-- Title -->
        <title>Facebook</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid bg-facebook-header">
            <div class="container header-properties">

            <!-- Logo -->

                <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">
                        <h3 class="fakebook-font">facebook</h3>
                    </div>

            <!-- login form -->

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <form action="#" method="post">

                    <!-- labels -->

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4 offset-sm-2 pl-3">
                                    <label for="emailphone" class="text-white form-label-text">Email or phone</label>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 pl-3">
                                        <label for="inputPassword" class="text-white form-label-text">Password</label>
                                    </div>
                            </div>

                    <!-- form controls -->

                            <div class="row input-selector mt-n1">
                                <div class="col-md-4 text-right mb-1 offset-sm-2 login-form-spacing">
                                    <input type="email" id="emailphone" name="email" required="required" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 text-right mb-1 login-form-spacing">
                                    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="password" placeholder="&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;" required>
                                </div>

                    <!-- submit -->

                                <div class="col-sm-2 text-right input-btn">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-facebook-login text-white col-form-label" name="button"><strong>Login</strong></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    <!-- forgotten -->

                            <div class="row pl-sm-5">
                                <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-5">
                                    <small class="form-text text-right mt-n2 mr-n2">
                                        <a href="#" class="forgotten-account">Forgotten account?</a>
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>

            <!-- login form end -->

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

            <!-- body -->

        <div class="container-fluid bg-body-content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row no-gutters">

                <!-- left side -->

                    <div class="col-sm-6 mt-sm-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <p class="facebook-intro-text col-sm-11">Facebook helps you connect and share with the people in your life.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="assets/img/world-map-png-35422.png" alt="lorem ipsum" class="img-fluid body-img">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <!-- right side (sign up form) -->

                    <div class="col-sm-6 mt-sm-4">
                        <div class="row no-gutters">
                            <div class="signup-form-text offset-sm-1 pl-sm-3">
                                <h3>Create an account</h3>
                                <p>It's quick and easy.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <!-- //form -->

                        <div class="row offset-sm-1 pl-sm-3">
                            <form class="signup-form-control" action="#" method="post">
                                <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-between mb-sm-2">
                                    <div>
                                        <label for="fname" class="sr-only">First Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ml-2">
                                        <label for="sname" class="sr-only">Surname</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="sname" class="form-control" placeholder="Surname">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row no-gutters mb-sm-2">
                                    <label for="mnum-email" class="sr-only">Mobile number or email address</label>
                                    <input type="email" id="mnum-email" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile number or email address">
                                </div>
                                <div class="row no-gutters mb-sm-3">
                                    <label for="newpassword" class="sr-only">New Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" id="newpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="New password">
                                </div>

                        <!-- DOB -->

                                <div class="row no-gutters mb-sm-2">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label for="bday" class="mb-n1 signup-form-bday row no-gutters">Birthday</label>
                                        <div class="row no-gutters mt-sm-2">
                                            <select id="bday" name="Day" class="dropdown-text col-sm-3">
                                                <option value="Day">Day</option>
                                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                                <option value="6">6</option>
                                                <option value="7">7</option>
                                                <option value="8">8</option>
                                                <option value="9">9</option>
                                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                                <option value="11">11</option>
                                                <option value="12">12</option>
                                                <option value="13">13</option>
                                                <option value="14">14</option>
                                                <option value="15">15</option>
                                                <option value="16">16</option>
                                                <option value="17">17</option>
                                                <option value="18">18</option>
                                                <option value="19">19</option>
                                                <option value="20">20</option>
                                                <option value="21">21</option>
                                                <option value="22">22</option>
                                                <option value="23">23</option>
                                                <option value="24">24</option>
                                                <option value="25">25</option>
                                                <option value="26">26</option>
                                                <option value="27">27</option>
                                                <option value="28">28</option>
                                                <option value="29">29</option>
                                                <option value="30">30</option>
                                                <option value="31">31</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <select class="dropdown-text col-sm-3" id="bday" name="month">
                                                <option value="Month">Month</option>
                                                <option value="January">Jan</option>
                                                <option value="Febraury">Feb</option>
                                                <option value="March">Mar</option>
                                                <option value="April">Apr</option>
                                                <option value="May">May</option>
                                                <option value="June">Jun</option>
                                                <option value="July">Jul</option>
                                                <option value="August">Aug</option>
                                                <option value="September">Sep</option>
                                                <option value="October">Oct</option>
                                                <option value="November">Nov</option>
                                                <option value="December">Dec</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <select class="dropdown-text col-sm-3" id="bday">
                                                <option value="Year">Year</option>
                                                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                                                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                                                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                                                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                                                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                                <option value="2017">2017</option>
                                                <option value="2018">2018</option>
                                                <option value="2019">2019</option>
                                                <option value="2020">2020</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <span class="question-circle-fa-1"><a href="#" class="pt-1 ml-2 fa fa-question-circle"></a></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                        <!-- DOB end -->
                        <!-- Radios -->

                                    <div class="row no-gutters">
                                        <label for="gender" class="signup-form-bday">Gender</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row no-gutters radio-text-gender pl-1">
                                        <label for="gender" class="mr-3 col-sm-2">
                                            <input type="radio" id="gender" name="Female"class="mr-1">Female
                                        </label>
                                        <label for="gender" class="mr-3 col-sm-2 text-center">
                                            <input type="radio" id="gender" name="Male" class="mr-1">Male
                                        </label>
                                        <label for="gender" class="mr-3 col-sm-2">
                                            <input type="radio" id="gender" name="Custom" class="mr-1">Custom
                                        </label>
                                        <span class="question-circle-fa"><a href="#" class="fa fa-question-circle"></a></span>
                                    </div>

                        <!-- Radios end -->

                                    <div class="row no-gutters">
                                        <small class="tc-text col-sm-7">
                                            <p>By clicking Sign Up, you agree to our <a href="#">Terms</a>, <a href="#">Data Policy</a> and <a href="#">Cookie Policy</a>. You may receive SMS notifications from us and can opt out at any time.</p>
                                        </small>
                                    </div>

                        <!-- Button -->
                                    <div class="row no-gutters mb-sm-4">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-signup-properties col-sm-6">Sign Up</button>
                                    </div>

                        <!-- Button end -->

                                    <div class="row no-gutters">
                                        <p class="form-bottom-note"><a href="#">Create a Page</a> for a celebrity, band or business.</p>
                                    </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                    <!-- //form end -->

                    </div>

                <!-- right side end -->

                </div>

            <!-- body row end -->

            </div>
        </div>

            <!-- footer -->

        <div class="container mt-sm-5">
            <div class="row no-gutters text-center">
                <ul class="list-inline footer-whitespace-parent">
                    <li class="list-inline-item">English (UK)</li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">اوردو</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">پشتو</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">العربية</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">हिन्दी</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">ਪੰਜਾਬੀ</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">বাংলা</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Deutsch</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">ગુજરાતી</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">فارسی</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Español</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item add-lang"><a href="#" class="fa fa-plus"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="row no-gutters splitter">
            </div>
            <div class="no-gutters">
                <ul class="list-inline footer-whitespace-parent space-between-lists my-sm-1">
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Messenger</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Facebook Lite</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">People</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Page categories</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Places</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Games</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Marketplace</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Groups</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Portal</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Local</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Fundraisers</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Create ad</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Create Page</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Developers</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Cookies</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">AdChoices</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-copyright-text">
                <p>Facebook &copy; 2020</p>
            </div>

        </div>

            <!-- footer end -->
    <!-- -------------------------------------------------------------
         JS files: jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS
    --------------------------------------------------------------- -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"          integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>               <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"             integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"            integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Custom CSS

```
    * {
    font-family: Arial;
}

.fakebook-font {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
}

.bg-facebook-header {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #3b5998, #3b5999, #47639e) !important;
}

.header-properties {
    max-height: 90px;
}

.form-label-text {
    font-size: 0.6rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.login-form-spacing {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}

.input-selector input {
    font-size: 0.6rem;
}

.input-btn {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}

 .input-selector input:focus {
    background: #fffbc9;
}

.btn-facebook-login {
    background-color: #4267b2;
    font-size: 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.175rem 0.45rem;
    border: 1px solid #29487d;
    border-radius: 0rem;
}

.btn-facebook-login:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: #29487d !important;
}

.forgotten-account {
    color: #9cb4d8;
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 75%;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.forgotten-account:hover {
    color: #9cb4d8 !important;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.bg-body-content {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #d3d8E8, #eaedf4, #fff) !important;
}

.body-img {
    height: auto;
}

.facebook-intro-text {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 0.9rem !important;
    color: #0e385f !important;
}

.signup-form-text {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #333333 !important;
}

.signup-form-text h3 {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.signup-form-text p {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.signup-form-control input {
    font-size: 0.86rem;
}

.signup-form-label {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.signup-form-bday {
    color: #90949c !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.table-cells {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}

.dropdown-text {
    font-size: 0.6rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0.25rem 0rem;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #90949c;
}

.radio-text-gender {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.question-circle-fa-1 a {
    color: #606770;
    font-size: 0.8rem !important;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.question-circle-fa a {
    color: #606770;
    padding-top: 0.2rem !important;
    text-align: right !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.tc-text {
    font-size: 0.5rem;
    /*  letter-spacing: 0.005rem;
    word-spacing: 0.5rem; */
    color: #777;
}

.tc-text a {
    color: #3b5998 !important;
}

.btn-signup-properties {
    background: linear-gradient(#67ae55, #578843);
    background-color: #69a74e;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #a4e388;
    border-color: #3b6e22 #3b6e22 #2c5115;
    border: 1px solid #3b6e22;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    padding: 0.175rem 0rem !important;
}

 .btn-signup-properties:hover {
     background: white !important;
     border: 1px solid #3b5998;
     box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #3b5998;
     color: #3b5998;
     text-shadow: none;
 }

.form-bottom-note {
    font-size: 0.6rem;
    color: #666;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.form-bottom-note a {
    color: #3b5998 !important;
}

.footer-whitespace-parent {
    font-size: 0rem !important;
}

.footer-whitespace-parent li {
    font-size: 0.6rem !important;
    color: #737373;
}

.footer-whitespace-parent li a {
    color: #385898;
}

.splitter {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddfe2;
}

.space-between-lists li {
    margin-right: 1.26321rem !important;
}

.add-lang a {
    height: 0.8rem;
    width: 1.5rem;
    background-color: #f5f6f7;
    border: 1px solid #ccd0d5;
    padding: 0.07rem;
    font-size: 0.5rem !important;
    color: #6a7180 !important;
}

.add-lang a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #ebedf0;
}

.footer-copyright-text {
    font-size: 0.5rem !important;
    color: #737373;
    margin-top: 0.8rem;
}
```

Comment: What are you seeing and what do you expect? An image or two may help us.

Comment: I checked it on fiddle by copy pasting the code, it seems fine on Chrome, can you please share screenshot of specific error which you are trying to highlight?

Also, please clear browser cache memory if issue persist or if browser is updated?

Comment: @Prashant Thanks for replying, I have added two SSs, since i'm not allowed to add photos directly in my post, stackoverflow has added links for them. kindly, check them out!

Comment: @j08691 I have added two screen captures in the post, kindly check them.